# How to exclude or remove NULL values from array and array_agg with PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

In the following request:

```
SELECT
  myid,
  min(name) AS name,
  array_agg(array[zip, city])) AS city
FROM my_table
WHERE name LIKE 'Doe'
GROUP BY myid
LIMIT 10
```

I get the following result:

```
+-------+------+-------------------+
| myid  | name | city              |
+-------+------+-------------------+
| A123  | Doe  | {{69,"Groville"}} |
| B456  | Doe  | {{NULL,NULL}}     |
+-------+------+-------------------+
```

How can I get rid of the `NULL` values and get an empty field for `city` instead ?

=== EDIT ===

Replaced `(array_agg(name))[1] AS name` by `min(name) AS name` in the query, as suggested by @a_horse_with_no_name.

Comment: Unrelated, but: why not use `min(name)` instead of first aggregating all names and then pick one

Comment: Because I didn't know it :) Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation.

```
SELECT myid,
       min(name) AS name,
       array_agg(array[zip, city]) filter (where num_nulls(zip, city) = 0) AS city
FROM my_table
WHERE name LIKE 'Doe'
GROUP BY myid
LIMIT 10
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`array_remove()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html):

```
array_agg(array_remove(array[zip, city], null))
```

Comment: I get this error: `ERROR:  cannot accumulate empty arrays, SQL state: 2202E`.